# Generating a barcode in Controller and displaying it in View

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, image, barcode

I'm trying to generate a barcode image in my controller (using Barcode Rendering Framework) and then pass that image to my view to be displayed. It's the first time I've tried something like this and I'm having a lot of problems.

Here's my code in the controller:

```
        string barcodeValue = "1234567";

        Code39BarcodeDraw barcode = BarcodeDrawFactory.Code39WithChecksum;

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        var barcodePic = barcode.Draw(barcodeValue, 50);

        barcodePic.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);

        model.Pic = barcodePic;
```

How do I display my ViewModel's "Pic" property in the View? I'm using @Html to display text boxes and everything else, but there's no @Html.Image that displays a System.Drawing.Image. I've read about converting the image to Byte[] or base64 string, but I don't know how to display those either.

Answer (score 1):

You can return a `ContentResult` with your memory stream. It should happen on a separate request that you embed.

```
string barcodeValue = "1234567";

Code39BarcodeDraw barcode = BarcodeDrawFactory.Code39WithChecksum;

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

var barcodePic = barcode.Draw(barcodeValue, 50);

barcodePic.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);

return Content(ms, "image/gif");
```